# Why does my ExecuteNonQuery alway return a value more than 0

Tags: c#, sql, executenonquery

Hi i am now coding for a search box that will get the data from sql and check if there is any of such data but when i run my code

```
public void checkValues()
    {
        using (connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        using (SqlCommand cmdMovname = new SqlCommand("select Film_name from product where Film_name like'%the value here is not in the sql data %'", connection))
        {
            connection.Open();

            if (cmdMovname.ExecuteNonQuery() != 0)
            {
                SetValues();
                find = "Search result for \"the value here is not in the sql data\"";
            }
            else if (cmdMovname.ExecuteNonQuery() == 0)
            {
                find = "Sorry , no search result for \"the value here is not in the sql data\"";
            }

        }
    }
```

the string value of find will always be "Search result for \"the value here is not in the sql data\"" 
can someone help me with this cause i am new to using sql database

Comment: Because the return value of `ExecuteNonQuery` for a select statement is always -1: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executenonquery(v=vs.110).aspx.

Comment: why are you re-executing the query in the `else if`??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using ExecuteReader instead. You are trying to execute a query, but using the ExecuteNonQuery function, which will return -1 in this situation.

[Reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/haa3afyz(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: Thanks i dodnt know that ExecuteNonQuery will return -1 by default